# How to stop overlapping spheres when sculpting with radial symmetry

Tags: sculpting

I am testing out sculpting with alphas, using an anchored stencil. I have a basic cuboid shape where I want to apply the alpha stencil to each of the 4 side faces. For this I am using a radial symmetry of 4 on the z axis to apply it on each face. The problem I'm having is that when I click and drag to sculpt the stencil, eventually the sculpting spheres from the adjacent sides enter the side that I'm sculpting, creating a distortion to the pattern I'm applying. Is there a better way to achieve what I want without radial symmetry perhaps, or are there setting to not overlap the radial sculpts?

Attached is an image of what I'm getting, and the settings used for the sculpt. Note the circular shapes on each side of the face, which are coming from the same sculpt happening on the adjacent faces.

Many thanks!

[image]